# .net c# null nested object in EF model

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I dont understand why the nested object is not null...

```
var client = db.Clients.Find(id);
if(client != null) {
    client.someNestedObject = null;

    var x = client.someNestedObject;
    //here, x is NOT NULL!!!??? (its a proxy but not null)
}
```

NestedObject model:

```
   public int id { get; set; }
   public virtual Client client { get; set; }
```

Client model:

```
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string client_name { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("someNestedObject")]
   public int id_nested { get; set; }

   public virtual NestedObject someNestedObject { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Related entities are not loaded by default see, [EF6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data) or [EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/).

Comment: thanks, is there any way to turn off lazy loading in just this specific case? I use this model in other parts on my application, and I want to use lazy loading in those places, just not in this specific case because here I want to serialize it... (in the link you provided, it says I can make the model not use lazy loading, but it will apply everywhere I use the model)